# Python 3.4.3 socket.sendto

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, network-programming, udp, icmp

I'm having a bit of trouble running the following code on Windows 7 and Python 3.4.3 version. The code is:

```
import socket
import sys

class TraceRoute(object):

    BADDR = "0.0.0.0" # default bind address - (all IPs)
    PORT = 33434 # default port
    ICMP = socket.getprotobyname('icmp')
    UDP = socket.getprotobyname('udp')

    desternation = ""
    ttl = 0 # we inrecement this by one each time.    

    # sockets
    reciever = None
    sender = None

    # finished?
    finished = False

    def __init__(self, desternation):
        self.desternation = socket.gethostbyname(desternation)

        self.reciever = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, self.ICMP)
        self.sender = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, self.UDP)

        # bind to reciever so we can listen for replies
        self.reciever.bind((self.BADDR, self.PORT))

    def next_server(self):
        """ Connects to next server 1 hop away from current server (i.e. server[ttl + 1]) """
        if self.finished:
            # we have nothing to do, just return
            return

        # first job increment the ttl on the socket
        self.ttl += 1
        self.sender.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, self.ttl)

        self.sender.sendto(bytes("", "UTF-8"), (self.desternation, self.PORT))
        current_server = self.reciever.recvfrom(512)[1][0] # get 512 bytes from the reciever
        self.display(current_server)

        if current_server == self.desternation:
            self.finished = True

    def display(self, address):
        """ Gets the hostname (if we can) and displays """
        try:
            name = socket.gethostbyaddr(address)[0]
            print "%s) %s (%s)" % (self.ttl, name, address)
        except socket.error:
            # we couldn't - we'll just tell them the IP address
            print "%s) %s" % (self.ttl, address)

    def __del__(self):
        """ Be good and close our sockets """
        try:
            self.reciever.close()
        except socket.error:
            # already closed
            pass

        try:
            self.sender.close()
        except socket.error:
            # already closed
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # lets get the address from the commandline args
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        # nothing been specified
        print "You need to give an address"
        print "%s <server>" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit() # we can't do anything.

    tracert = TraceRoute(sys.argv[1])
    while not tracert.finished:
        tracert.next_server()
```

Once I start the script nothing happens and it looks like it's in the endless loop. The only way to  stop it is to use CTRL+BREAK key combination. Any kind of help is more than welcome. Thanks in advance, Tomislav.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any timeout when waiting for the ICMP reply:

```
current_server = self.reciever.recvfrom(512)[1][0] # get 512 bytes from the reciever
```

You should not assume that every node in your path will have ICMP replies enabled.

Also it seems that your script finish condition is flawed. You will set tracert.finished to true when you will get the ICMP reply from your destination. Why would your destination reply to you using ICMP when you are sending UDP ping packets?

EDIT: If you are going to work more with network programming I *strongly* recommend you to download and learn Wireshark.